# Having trouble with the same origin policy

Tags: javascript, python

My java script post request is giving this error  "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

JavaScript (Client) post code

```js
function doapost(exam){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/pexam",
        data: exam,
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(e){alert("worked")}, // The function to call on success
         error: function(e){alert("never worked")},      
    })
}
```

Python (web service) post code

```py
class postexamhandeler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        owner = self.request.get('owner')
        name = self.request.get('ename')
        date = self.request.get('edate')
        leangth = self.request.get('eleangth')
        pencil = self.request.get('epencil')
        pen = self.request.get('epen')
        calculator = self.request.get('ecalculator')
        ruller = self.request.get('eruller')
        type = self.request.get('etype')
        self.response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
        self.response.headers['charset'] = "utf-8"
        if len(name) > 0 and len(type) > 0:
            self.response.out.write('{ "response": "OK"}')
        else:
            self.response.out.write('{ "response": "ERROR"}')
        exm = makeexam(id= owner)
        exm.ename = name
        exm.edate = date
        exm.eleangth = leangth
        exm.epencil = pencil
        exm.epen = pen
        exm.ecalculator = calculator
        exm.eruller = ruller
        exm.etype = type
        exm.put()    
        self.response.out.write('{ "response": "OK"}')
```

Comment: Are you in control of the server? If so what language is the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allow cross origin requests from the server. In PHP, this does the trick

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

From looking at your python code I suppose this should help (.. I suppose)

```
class postexamhandeler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        owner = self.request.get('owner')
        name = self.request.get('ename')
        date = self.request.get('edate')
        leangth = self.request.get('eleangth')
        pencil = self.request.get('epencil')
        pen = self.request.get('epen')
        calculator = self.request.get('ecalculator')
        ruller = self.request.get('eruller')
        type = self.request.get('etype')
        self.response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
        self.response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
        self.response.headers['charset'] = "utf-8"
        if len(name) > 0 and len(type) > 0:
            self.response.out.write('{ "response": "OK"}')
        else:
            self.response.out.write('{ "response": "ERROR"}')
        exm = makeexam(id= owner)
        exm.ename = name
        exm.edate = date
        exm.eleangth = leangth
        exm.epencil = pencil
        exm.epen = pen
        exm.ecalculator = calculator
        exm.eruller = ruller
        exm.etype = type
        exm.put()    
        self.response.out.write('{ "response": "OK"}')
```

This should add the cors response header

```
self.response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
```

Comment: Setting "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" to "*" whitelists the entire Internet. It can be useful to test something out. But it shouldn't be done in production. It basically negates the security benefits of CORS.

Answer (score 0):

Use `withCredentials` option for cross-domain request

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/pexam",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    xhrFields: {
         withCredentials: true
    }
}.done(function() {
   // your code here
});
```

But server must also enable credentials by setting the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials response header to “true”

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

and one more required header

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://yourdomain.com
```

More information about [CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)